# finding missing element in a set consisting of element from 1 to n, with n-1 elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

The problem is to find the missing number in a set of elements, which is of size n and has elements from 1 to n-1. For e.g in `S = {5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3}`, the missing element is  `4`.

Now I understand that if we perform XOR operation on elements of set and then XOR the result of previous operation with number from 1 to n in the following manner we get the missing number :

```
5 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 3 = 4 = X

1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 = 0 = Y
```

now on doing `X ^ Y` we get the result `4`.

I am unable to understand how is this happening. Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XOR operation, which we'll denote $\oplus$, has three important properties:

- It is associative: $a \oplus (b \oplus c) = (a \oplus b) \oplus c$.
- It is commutative: $a \oplus b = b \oplus a$.
- For any $a$, we have $a \oplus a = 0$.

That means that, in your case,

$$ (5 \oplus 1 \oplus 2 \oplus 6 \oplus 7 \oplus 3) \oplus (1 \oplus 2 \oplus 3 \oplus 4 \oplus 5 \oplus 6 \oplus 7) \\
= (1\oplus1) \oplus (2\oplus2) \oplus (3\oplus 3) \oplus (\color{red}{4}) \oplus (5\oplus5) \oplus (6\oplus6) \oplus (7\oplus7) = 4. $$

Comment: that was fairly easy , thanks a lott !! I guess i need to practice more !! :P

Comment: Note: If your numbers range from 0 .. 2^(n-1), e.g. because they are the set of values that can be represented by an n digit/bit binary number, observe that 0^1^2^3==0 (and indeed is zero for almost all such sets), so you don't actually need to calculate that part; the xor-reduction of just the numbers in your list _is_ the missing number, without having to include the "index"/expected values in the xor-reduction too. The only exception is n==1, where you have to xor the xor-reduction with 1 to find the missing number.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (using `^` for `XOR`): the operator is commutative, associative, and `a ^ 0 = a`, `a ^ a = 0` so:

```
5 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 3 = X

1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 = Y
```

implies `Y = X ^ 4` therefore:

```
X ^ Y = X ^ (X ^ 4) = (X ^ X) ^ 4 = 0 ^ 4 = 4
```